# How can I see my item-specific progress on the Daedric Walker achievement?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

The Stats screen shows how many Daedric quests I have completed, but I can't remember whether I successfully got the Daedric items from the quests (some are miss-able), and my collection disappeared from my storage in a night of drunken house rearranging.

Is there some way to see which I have collected, console command or otherwise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best you can do I'm afraid is to use the command **getstage [quest ID]** on the various  [Daedric quests](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Daedric_Quests).  The id for all the daedric quests goes from DA01 up to DA16.

Once you get the stage number, you can look up the corresponding stage id on the UESP page to determine if you've successfully completed it.

For example, if **[getstage da10](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_House_of_Horrors)** returns 200, then that means you should have received Molag Bal's Mace at some point.

If you really want to get those items back you can use player.additem [itemid].

Comment: @Vaishali unfortunately yes